# Use value from parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Ruby on Rails 4

I am passing a hidden value from my form.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :applied_program, :value => @applied_program.id %>
```

This is what is posted:

```
"applied_program"=>"891"} ...
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find AppliedProgram with 'id'={"applied_program"=>"891"})
```

I am trying to update attributes of the applied program in my controller.

I don't know how to assign the parameter to the record. This is what I am trying, but it can't find it based on the parameters passed.

I also tried passing just @applied_program without the .id but then I have the same problem finding it with the Object information. :/

```
@applied_program = AppliedProgram.find(applied_program_params)
```

The controller white list:

```
def applied_program_params
  params.require(:payment).permit(:applied_program)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
@applied_program = AppliedProgram.find(payment_params[:applied_program])

def payment_params
  params.require(:payment).permit(:applied_program)
end
```

Your data will be passed like below from the form to the controller

```
{:permit => {:applied_program => 891}}
```

UPDATE:

```
applied_program_id = payment_params.delete(:applied_program)
@payment = Payment.new(payment_params)
@applied_program = AppliedProgram.find(applied_program_id)
```

Comment: The problem is I am using Payment.new(payment_params) and :applied_program does not exist in that table so it yells at me.

Comment: @DDDD Alternatively, I might consider changing the structure so the `applied_program` field does not appear in the `payment_params` hash. That way you don't have to worry about removing it from the hash. Ultimately, if its not relevant to that resource, then it shouldn't be in the parameters for that resource.

Comment: It POSTs as "applied_program" => "891" but then on the @payment = Payment.new(payment_params) is gives ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute: applied_program):
  app/controllers/payments_controller.rb:20:in `create'

Comment: @PaulRichter, do you have a reference because not sure how to do that with one submit button.

Comment: @DDDD Take a look at the [`hidden_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag) helper; you would replace your `f.hidden_field` with this instead. That'll put the `applied_program` value in the root of the parameter map, so you would access it like `params[:applied_program]` instead. Worst case I can write an answer demonstrating this if you need, but hopefully its straightforward enough.

Comment: @PaulRichter, I follow you except for how to handle this with the white listed params. If its not white listed somehow it yells at me.

Comment: @DDDD Hmm, you're not still trying to access it like `payment_params[:applied_program]` anymore, are you? If you are, remember we took it out of the `payment` sub-parameter list; its now in the root `params` now. If that's not the case, what's the actual error message, and how are you attempting to use it?

Comment: I ended up doing it Vimsha's way +1. I just added the attribute to the payment table, thank you though Paul Richter.

Comment: @DDDD Cool, I'm glad you got it working, but if I've understood your scenario properly, you've added a column(applied_program) to a table(payments) that has nothing to do with that table, correct? If I'm misunderstanding, I apologize, I'm just concerned you've taken a messy approach to solve the problem. I don't mind [moving this to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57588/discussion-between-paul-richter-and-dddd) if you want to discuss it further (and avoid cluttering Vimsha's inbox)